# Reproducing sumproduct in R into matrix

Tags: r

I have created the following data frame:

`df <- data.frame(names1=c('dog','dog','mouse','cat','dog','cat','cat','dog','mouse','mouse'), names2=c('cat','dog','cat','cat','cat','dog','dog','dog','mouse','cat'), values=c(11,5,41,25,101,78,12,41,6,77))`

and this following matrix which yields:

`my_matrix <- matrix(data=0,nrow = length(unique(df$names1)),ncol = length(unique(df$names2))) rownames(my_matrix) <- c('dog','mouse','cat') colnames(my_matrix) <- c('dog','mouse','cat')`

|  | **dog** | **mouse** | **cat** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **dog** | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **mouse** | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **cat** | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Now I want two things.

1. Populate the empty matrix with the counts (number of element intersects) coming from df$names1 and df$names2

the result should be:

|  | dog | mouse | cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **dog** | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| **mouse** | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| **cat** | 2 | 0 | 1 |

Populate the empty matrix with the sums (where element intersect) coming from df$names1 and df$names2

the result should be:

|  | dog | mouse | cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **dog** | 46 | 0 | 112 |
| **mouse** | 0 | 6 | 118 |
| **cat** | 90 | 0 | 25 |

I have tried something like

`for(i in 1:3){ for(j in 1:3){ my_matrix[i,j] <-  sum(df$names1 == df$names2) } }`

`print(my_matrix)`

but dont get the desired results

your help is much appreciated, may thanks

update:

thanks for the may comments, but does anybody have an idea how to do it with the for loop. like looping through each element of the matrix and then assigning the value accordingly? so far I have tested something like

```
for(i in 1:nrow(my_matrix)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(my_matrix)){
    
    my_matrix[i,j] <-  sum(df$values & df$names1[i] == df$names2[j] & df$names2[j] == df$names1[i]) 
  }
}

print(my_matrix)
```

but it does not work as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated answer with missing animals**

*original data*

```
df <- data.frame(names1=c('dog','dog','mouse','cat','dog','cat','cat','dog','mouse','mouse'), names2=c('cat','dog','cat','cat','cat','dog','dog','dog','mouse','cat'), values=c(11,5,41,25,101,78,12,41,6,77))
```

*we use data.table here and make it a data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

*define the animals that need to be included in the order you want*

```
o <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "bear", "monkey")
```

*now append your data with all animals and set their values to NA*

```
df <- rbindlist(list(df, data.table(names1 = o, names2 = o, values = NA)))
```

*to prevent counting NA's change the fun.aggregate*

```
dcast(df, factor(names1, levels = o) ~ factor(names2, levels = o), fun.aggregate = function(x) length(na.omit(x)), value.var = "values")

   names1 cat dog mouse bear monkey
1:    cat   1   2     0    0      0
2:    dog   2   2     0    0      0
3:  mouse   2   0     1    0      0
4:   bear   0   0     0    0      0
5: monkey   0   0     0    0      0

dcast(df, factor(names1, levels = o) ~ factor(names2, levels = o), fun.aggregate = function(x) sum(na.omit(x)), value.var = "values")

   names1 cat dog mouse bear monkey
1:    cat  25  90     0    0      0
2:    dog 112  46     0    0      0
3:  mouse 118   0     6    0      0
4:   bear   0   0     0    0      0
5: monkey   0   0     0    0      0
```

**my original answer**

If the output being a matrix is not requirement, you can achieve it easily by going from "long to wide", I use `data.table` here with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

dcast(df, names1 ~ names2, fun.aggregate = length)

#    names1 cat dog mouse
# 1:    cat   1   2     0
# 2:    dog   2   2     0
# 3:  mouse   2   0     1

dcast(df, names1 ~ names2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "values")

#    names1 cat dog mouse
# 1:    cat  25  90     0
# 2:    dog 112  46     0
# 3:  mouse 118   0     6
```

**updated example with ordering**

```
o <- unique(df$names1)
dcast(df, factor(names1, levels = o) ~ factor(names2, levels = o), fun.aggregate = length)
dcast(df, factor(names1, levels = o) ~ factor(names2, levels = o), fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "values")
```

Comment: many thanks is there a way how I can set in the dcast function the column and row order? in this case its dog, mouse, cat

Comment: you can do if you want, see updated example, you can dcast the factors with the provided levels. I took `o <- unique(df$names1)` so both rows and columns will be ordered in order of names1 in your df.

Comment: Thats great, thank you. The benefit I see in the matrix approach is that additional elements can be added to determine that they do not occur in the two columns in df. To be specific, lets say I want to check that there are no birds col1 and col 2 in df. Using and populating the empty matrix would yield 0 for birds, however, if I add "birds" to your vector o i do not get an additional row and a additional column birds populated with 0. So lets say I create a 4x4 matrix (adding birds into row and column) and sum over names1 and names2

Comment: Ok I will update my example, but please next time make a reproducable example including such scenario's.